# List Python packages that will be installed from requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

In my `requirements.txt` I have packages defined in following manner:

```
Django ~= 2.2.0
```

It means that when I use `pip install -r requirements.txt` pip will find the latest available `2.2.x` version and install it along with all dependencies.
What I need is requirements-formatted list of all packages with explicit versions that will be installed but without actually installing any packages. So example output would be something like:

```
Django==2.2.23
package1==0.2.1
package2==1.4.3
...
```

So in other words I'm looking for something like `pip freeze` results but without installing anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+list+dependencies+without+installation

Comment: If I remember correctly [_`johnnydep`_](https://pypi.org/project/johnnydep/) is the only tool that does what you need. It does dependency resolution without actually installing anything and without needing any of the dependencies to be installed. The other tools mentioned only do the dependency tree of what is already installed in the environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pip-compile` is what you need!
Doc: https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools)

```sh
python -m pip install pip-tools
pip-compile requirements.txt --output-file requirements-all.txt
```

The pip-compile command lets you compile a requirements.txt file from your dependencies, this way you can pip install you dependencies to always have the same environment

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Try [pipdetree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) or [pip-tree](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tree/).

### Explanation

`pip`, contrary to most package managers, doesn't have a big dependency graph to look up. What it does is that it lets arbitrary setup code to be executed, which automatically pulls the dependencies. This means that, for example, a package could manage their dependencies in an other way than putting them in `requirements.txt` (see [fastai](https://github.com/fastai/fastai) for an example of a project that handles the dependencies differently).

So, there is, theoretically, no other way to see all the dependencies than to actually run an install on an isolated environment, see what was pulled, then delete the environment (because it could potentially be the same part of the code that does the installation and that brings the dependencies). You could actually do that with `venv`.

In practice, tools like [pipdetree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) or [pip-tree](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tree/) fetch the dependencies based on some standardization of the requirements (most packages separate the dependencies and the installation, and actually let pip handle both).